# Gradle sync failed: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "PATH_HASHING_STRATEGY"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

This pops when build a project exported from Unity 2017.4 with Android Studio, is there any config error within android studio?

Gradle sync failed: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "PATH_HASHING_STRATEGY" the class loader